Polynomial with non-negative coefficients, crossing identity multiple times
I am trying to find or construct a polynomial $ f(x) $ that satisfies the following properties:

$ f(x) $ has nonnegative for all terms.
$ f(1) = 1 $.
The function $ f(x) = x $ has multiple (>1) answers that are not $-1,0,1$?

It's obvious to see that $f(x) = x, x^3, \dots $ satisfy the conditions and $f(x)-x$ have solutions at $-1,0,1$ but nothing else. But I'm wondering if there is any polynomial with those traits that has more than two roots. I would like to know if such a polynomial exists, and if not, what is the proof that it does not exist?

Here's my idea. Consider the polynomial $f(x) = x + (x-1)(a_0 + a_1x + ... + a_nx^n)$. Clearly it satisfies the second condition $f(1)=1$. To make it satisfy the first condition we have to require the coefficients of the function to be nonnegative:
$$
x + (x-1)\sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k = x + \sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^{k+1} - \sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k = x - a_0 + \sum_{k=1}^n (a_{k-1}-a_k) x^{k} + a_nx^{n+1}.
$$
Thus we have these conditions:
$$
a_0 \le 0,
$$
$$
1 + a_0 - a_1 \ge 0,
$$
$$
a_{k-1}-a_k \ge 0, k = 2,..n,
$$
$$
a_n \ge 0,
$$
or $a_0 \le 0 \le a_n \le a_{n-1} \le ... \le a_2 \le a_1 \le 1 + a_0$.
Thus we need now to look for polynomials of the form $g(x) = a_0 + a_1x + ... + a_nx^n$ with coefficients satisfying $a_0 \le 0 \le a_n \le a_{n-1} \le ... \le a_2 \le a_1 \le 1 + a_0$ and having at least two roots on desired subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

For $f(x) = x^3, x^5 \ldots$ (part of the examples that OP provided), $f(x) - x$ has 3 roots in the interval $[-1, 1]$, namely $-1, 0, 1$.
Thus, such a polynomial exists.
Note: I'm guessing that condition 1 should be modified to "nonnegative coefficient for all terms", based on OP's examples.

you're absolutely right, I think my question needed more conditions, that there are "non-trivial" solutions other than $-1,0,1$.
